# i want to parse date in my format but is give me exception in android?

Tags: java, android, date-parsing

i am trying to convert original datetime in to my format but is  give me exception

my date :**2014-01-22 13:24:03** in this format now i want to convert

> Date.java

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd k:mm:ss");
Date date = format.parse("2014-01-22 13:24:03");

String strdate = android.text.format.DateFormat.format("dd.MM kk:mm", date).toString();
```

> i want output like this
>
> 22.1 13.24

```
Logcat Error



01-22 13:24:24.421: W/System.err(27821): java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2014-01-22 13:24:03" (at offset 10)
    01-22 13:24:24.431: W/System.err(27821): at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:626)
```

Comment: Are you *sure* you want `kk` rather than `HH`? Will you really get an hour of `24` after midnight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code

```
  try
    {
      SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
      Date date = format.parse("2014-01-22 13:24:03");
      String newdate = "" + date.getDate() + "." + date.getMonth() + " " + date.getHours() + "." + date.getMinutes(); 
    }
  catch( Exception e) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a `T` in your pattern, but not in the date you're trying to parse. Get rid of the `T` in your pattern and the problem should go away.

From [SimpleDateFormat documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

```
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ" --> 2001-07-04T12:08:56.235-0700
```

Note the T in the pattern matches the corresponding T in the date string being parsed.

It's also a little odd that your pattern includes `Kk`, as upper and lowercase k have different meanings:

> k Hour in day (1-24)
>
> K Hour in am/pm (0-11)

Answer (score 0):

The correct pattern for that date format is: `yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm:ss`.

Then, in order to format the date the way you need, you can use this pattern: `dd.M' 'HH.mm`.

Answer (score 0):

Try do it in that way and review your formatting string.:)

```
String ISO_8601 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH-mm-ss");
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat();
formatter.format(date);
```